# Is there any way to get name of the file used in --set-file parameter during helm install/upgrade/template within the helm chart template files?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

`helm template sample ./sample-chart --set-file configMaps="{app1.yaml,app2.yaml}"`

Is the command i am using to set file as values to the chart. And in the chart i am using it set the files as config map.

configmap.yaml:

```
{{ range $configMap := .Values.configMaps }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ <<file-name> }}-cm
data: 
{{ $configMap | indent 2}}
{{ end }}
```

I want to set the config map name, the name of the files whose content is in use as data .i.e app1,app2 in this case. Is there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can ask Helm to [read the file itself](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) when the template is instantiated.  Instead of passing in the contents of the files, pass their names directly.

Adapting [the basic example](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#basic-example) from the Helm documentation, you could write a ConfigMap

```
{{- $files := .Files }}
{{- range .Values.configMaps }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ . }}-cm
data:
  {{ . }}: |-
    {{ $files.Get . }}
{{- end }}
```

(The actual example puts all of the files into a single ConfigMap and that might be a little easier to manage.)

When you run this, you'd give the names of the files and not their contents at the command line (or an auxiliary values file)

```
helm template sample ./sample-chart --set configMaps="{app1.yaml,app2.yaml}"
```

Comment: .Files can only be used to get files within the chart. I want to access files outside the chart, and so i am trying to use --set-file ,which can convert file external to helm chart into multiline string key value.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this issue, I have changed the format of the key in --set-file argument.

`helm template sample ./sample-chart --set-file configMapFiles.app1-yaml.data="app1.yaml" --set-file configMapFiles.app2-yaml.data="app2.yaml"`

And I have changed the template for configMap.yaml as

configmap.yaml :

```
{{ range $configMapName$configMap := .Values.configMapFiles }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{$configMapName}}-cm
data: 
{{$configMap | indent 2}}: |-
{{ $configMap.data | indent 4}}
---
{{ end }}
```

This allowed me to set filename in the metadata of the configMap.